# Change yarn to npm when using npx install react-create-app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-hooks, yarnpkg

I already uninstalled yarn but when I run node package execute (npx) create-react-app, yarn lock is still there but i can run it with node package manager (npm) start. How can I get I back to package-lock json or npm version when i create-react-app using npx create-react-app.

I wanna use npm for react and react-native projects.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the `yarn.lock` and run `npm install` and it will generate a `package-lock.json`.

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json